# 32 bit vs 64 bit system - Informix Client SDK

Tags: informix

If I create an Informix SSIS package in my 32 bit system using 32 bit Client SDK and deployed it in 64 bit server. Will it create issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a package is using 32-bit components (e.g. OLEDB libraries), you will need to choose the "32-bit runtime" option on the Advanced tab when running the package on a 64-bit server.

[image: Execute Package Wizard]

(I know this is an old question; just adding an answer for posterity.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where this advanced tab will be available?

Comment: This is the window that appears when you right click a package in Management Studio and choose Execute. Note that it might be slightly different in newer versions; I took this screenshot in SSMS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You would need the 32-bit CSDK or Informix Connect (effectively the CSDK Runtime) on the 64-bit system (as well as a 64-bit CSDK or I-Connect for 64-bit applications).  Apart from that, I believe that it should work.  If it runs into problems, it is because of the Windows registry and the need for separate INFORMIXDIRs.

On 64-bit Unix systems, it was common to have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Informix CSDK or I-Connect on a single machine in separate INFORMIXDIRs.  These days, there is less 32-bit code — there are no longer any 32-bit servers on 64-bit Unix systems, and usually there isn't a 32-bit CSDK either.